# Wrong number or type in a loop

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, declare

getting this error:

```
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 19:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DAYS'
```

So it's an issue with that bolded "days" ...why?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
  TYPE lyrics IS OBJECT
  ( date_name   VARCHAR2(8)
  , gift_name   VARCHAR2(24));
/

DECLARE
  TYPE days IS TABLE OF lyrics;
  TYPE gifts IS TABLE OF lyrics;
 lv_dates DAYS :=
                  **days**('first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth', 'eleventh', 'twelth');
```

Comment: Please tag the programming language you are using. And provide more info, so people can help you.

Comment: thanks! just added that, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this; elements inside the array must be "objects", so you have to specify `lyrics` within the code:

```
SQL> create or replace
  2    type lyrics is object
  3    ( date_name   varchar2(8)
  4    , gift_name   varchar2(24));
  5  /

Type created.

SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    type days is table of lyrics;
  3    lv_dates days := days();
  4  begin
  5    lv_dates := days(lyrics('first', 'second'), lyrics('third', 'fourth'));
  6  end;
  7  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```